# Embedded systems development folder structure

Tags: maven, embedded, directory, embedded-linux

I'm starting a big project to run on a PIC32, and like every big project, code organization it's very important. Likewise, folder structure too.

In desktop software development I use my own folder structure (very similar to [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)), but like every applications we make, desktop and embedded implementations will have differences.

So, in your embedded systems project, what's your folder structure? Is there any ["maven like standard](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)" to embedded systems?

Comment: For those of us who don't know anything about Maven, can someone explain in a few sentences what the Maven project does - particularly what might be special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just "my folder structure" and by no means ultimate, but the project has a couple years, the product is already deployed and upgrades still actively developed - and I found the structure quite comfortable to use.

as separate projects:

- Firmware (main, monolithic app for doing The Thing)
- WWW (control over HTTP)
- misc tools
- Lang (translations of all strings)
- Common (a set of structures, defines and the likes included and shared by all).

Then, within Firmware:

- cpp (sources)

  - Appmanager (central point binding them all)
  - Events (event pump, task pump, also threading)
  - gfx (built-in screen GUI)
  - Net (TCP/IP based communication)
  - Interface (all other I/O - rs232, CAN, touchscreen, LCD screen, SPI etc)
  - Log
  - Utils (utility classes)
  - subdirectories for all major modules of the algorithm. Config file access, input processing, computation, overseer, watchdog,
- data (config files)
- [root directory] (short, trivial `main.cpp` and `global_include.h` which is included from every file - major configuration #defines.)

Comment: It looks like you do not separate source files in layers (app, transport layer, hardware abstraction), is it correct? I always find it difficult, I want to separate in modules like you do, but I also want to separate in layers. I can't find a practical way to do both, which bothers me.

Comment: @Gauthier: You can slice horizontally and bundle seven unrelated "top layer" elements apart from another bundle of unrelated "lower layer" (which looks neat but doesn't really help) or slice vertically and have, say, gfx-hardware interface, gfx drawing procedures, gfx UI engine and the UI screens definitions bundled, which allows you to easily create a new widget class if a screen needs it, have the widget drawn according to a new paradigm in the drawing layer, and have the raw driver close by if drawing procedures need special tricks. Layers: subdirs/files, Theme: main directories.